# How to solve this system of differential equations? $\dot{x}=3x-3y+5e^{2t},\ \dot{y}=3x-3y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of 2nd order differential equations ($\dot x$ denotes the derivative with respect to $t$, $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$):
$$\begin{cases} 
\dot{x}=3x-3y+5e^{2t} &(1)\\
\dot{y}=3x-3y &(2)
\end{cases}$$

So far, I have done the following:

Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $t$,
$$\ddot{x}=3\dot x -3\dot y +10e^{2t}$$
Substituting $\dot y$,
$$\ddot{x}=3\dot x -9x+9y+10e^{2t}$$
$$\ddot{x}-3\dot x +9x = 9y+10e^{2t}$$
Doing the same for $y$ gives
$$\ddot y+3\dot y+9y = 9x+15e^{2t}$$

I don't know where to go further with this. I don't think I can use the method of undetermined coefficients here since the RHS is a function of both $t$ and another variable ($x$ or $y$).

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D3x-3y%2B5e%5E%7B2t%7D%2C%20y%27%3D3x-3y) gives a neat (not messy) solution to the problem, so I assume we don't need some crazy methods to solve this.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use the eigenvalue/eigenvector method to solve such problems as a systematic way which always works. Sometimes one can find short cuts. But if this was in a text book, was it in the linear systems section of the textbook where you are expected to use eigenvectors?

Comment: @Nasser I was never introduced to any vector/matrix based way of solving DEs; this is just a differential equations question.

Comment: Well, this is the standard method actually to solve a system of first order ode's.  Here is example [solving-system-of-linear-differential-equations-by-eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/solving-system-of-linear-differential-equations-by-eigenvalues) and many more on the net. This is a very important method as it works on any system of linear odes'. You just need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvector of the A matrix and you get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that

$$
\dot x-\dot y = 5e^{2t}\Rightarrow x-y = \frac 52 e^{2t}+ C_0
$$

so you now can substitute and solve separately.